# Split string by space and strip newline char

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that looks like:

```
d4 c3 b2 a1 02 00 04 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
ff ff 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
36 00 00 00 36 00 00 00  00 1c 23 10 f8 f1 00 1b 
17 01 10 20 08 00 45 00  00 28 df 27 40 00 80 06 
2b 87 c7 08 1a 0a 0a 05  05 0a 5c ea 5c ea c2 1f
```

There are many more lines that I skipped. I want to put each of the numbers in a list. When I use `.split`, it returns me a list of not just numbers, but also spaces and `\n`'s, because there are two spaces in the middle of the matrix and there are newlines at the end of each line. So I got:

```
['d4', 'c3', 'b2', 'a1', '02', '00', '04', '00', '', '00', …, '\nff', 'ff', '00'…]
```

How can I get just the numbers to be in the list, not anything else?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you use `.split(" ")`, then your program will split on every single space, and not on any other whitespace. If you use `.split()` instead, the program will take into account multiple spaces, newlines, tabs and all other forms of whitespace. That should get you what you're looking for.

```
>>> teststr = "a   v w   ef sdv   \n   wef"
>>> print(teststr)
a   v w   ef sdv   
   wef
>>> teststr.split()
['a', 'v', 'w', 'ef', 'sdv', 'wef']
>>> teststr.split(" ")
['a', '', '', 'v', 'w', '', '', 'ef', 'sdv', '', '', '\n', '', '', 'wef']
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `split()` without any arguments will split the contents on any whitespaces and also group together several whitespaces.

Here is an example:

```
s = """d4 c3 b2 a1 02 00 04 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
ff ff 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
36 00 00 00 36 00 00 00  00 1c 23 10 f8 f1 00 1b 
17 01 10 20 08 00 45 00  00 28 df 27 40 00 80 06 
2b 87 c7 08 1a 0a 0a 05  05 0a 5c ea 5c ea c2 1f"""

data = s.split()
```

In this case, `data` will look like this:

```
['d4', 'c3', 'b2', 'a1', '02', '00', '04', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', '00', '00', '01', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '36', '00', '00', '00', '36', '00', '00', '00', '00', '1c', '23', '10', 'f8', 'f1', '00', '1b', '17', '01', '10', '20', '08', '00', '45', '00', '00', '28', 'df', '27', '40', '00', '80', '06', '2b', '87', 'c7', '08', '1a', '0a', '0a', '05', '05', '0a', '5c', 'ea', '5c', 'ea', 'c2', '1f']
```

Answer (score -1):

The [python string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) documentation has a huge list of things you can do to strings.

What's odd is that the `.split()` is not eliminating all of your whitespace when, as mentioned above by TheSoundDefense, it should.

To get rid of the newlines, try using the `.replace(<target>,<replacement>)` method like so:

```
a = '11 11 11 11  11 11 11 11 \n22 22 22 22  22 22 22 22 \n'
b = a.replace('\n',' ')
c = b.split()
print c
>>> ['11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '22', '22', '22', '22', '22', '22', '22', '22']
```

Comment: This will fail in the case of something like "00\nff".

Comment: Fixed it. I only really provided the .replace option since OP specified that .split() wasn't working for him.

Comment: This `replace` has no effect at all if the OP is really using `split()`; if the OP is using `split(" ")` as TheSoundDefense suspects, then this only solves the problem for `'\n'`, not for double spaces or anything else. I can't think of any scenario where this would actually solve the problem.

Comment: I mentioned that in my post. I wanted to help but did not have enough rep to comment, so I posted instead. At least I cited docs, if anything.